# VBA - Passing string variable to formula yields "application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, string, formula

I'm experiencing the following issue:

`Sheets("Workbook 1 ").Range("N" & integerv).Formula = "=Workbook2!""" & column_string & """ 3)"`

(integerv being some integer) keeps returning " Object-defined or application-defined error".

column_string is a string variable obtained by

`column_string = Split(Cells(a,b).Address(True,False), "$")(0)`

essentially just containing the column letter of the cell I want to reference.

Am I passing the string variable incorrectly ? And what would my code have to look like if I wanted to additionally pass an integer variable instead of "3" ?

Any help appreciated, I've been stuck with this for a fair while now.

Comment: Debugging hint: use `Debug.Print` to print the intended formula to see if it is what you think it is, before attempting to write it to the cell. I think you've got extra quotes.

Comment: Is 'Workbook2' a sheet name? If yes, would you like to create a link to a cell of this worksheet?

Comment: setting `column_string ` to `B` (as example), the formula results in `=Workbook2!"B" 3)` which is obviously invalid. Use an intermediate variable to create the formula-string and check with the debugger.

Comment: `Sheets("Workbook 1 ").Range("N" & integerv).Formula = "=Workbook2!" & column_string & "3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Just a Thought or Two About Formulas in VBA

How would you write your formula for column `A` in `Excel`?

```
=Workbook2!A3
```

In VBA you would do this:

```
rng.formula = "=Workbook2!A3"
```

You can aslo write it like this:

```
rng.Formula = "=Work" & "book2" & "!A3"
```

or like this:

```
rng.Formula = "=" & "Work" & "book" & "2" & "!" & "A3"
```

But of course in this case (your post) you wanna write it like this:

```
rng.Formula = "=Workbook2!" & "A" & "3"
```

Now when you make it dynamic, you know what to do:

```
rng.Formula = "=Workbook2!" & column_string & "3"
```

As `FunThomas` mentioned in the comments you can use a variable (and you should especially when there is a more complicated one). Then you could create a new Sub just for the formula and write...

```
Dim strFormula As String
strFormula = "=Workbook2!" & "A" & "3"
```

...and in the Immediate window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) see the written result with...

```
Debug.Print strFormula
```

...and modify the formula until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You my try the formula in this way:

```
Dim b As Long, column_string As String
b = 2: column_string = "C" 'the result simulation of your extraction using Split
 Sheets("Workbook 1 ").Range("N" & integerv).Formula = "=Workbook2!" & column_string & 3
 'having the b variable value, no need to extract the column letter:
 Sheets("Workbook 1 ").Range("N" & integerv).Formula = "=Workbook2!" & cells(3, b).Address(0, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I did not know you can use ``` & Cells(3,b).Address(0,0) & ``` in the formula. that simplified things greatly.

Comment: @mj_u: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. This will be helpful for somebody else searching for a similar issue. **I do not refer to my answer**! Please, do it for one of the answers looking more useful to you...